# How can i detect browser support of flash?

Tags: flash

This my HTML but if the browser does not support flash then i want to replace image in flash part

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if(typeof navigator.plugins['Shockwave Flash']!=='undefined'){
                alert('support');
            }else{
                alert('not support');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Empty -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does that have to do with PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is no way to detect Flash support in php**. php is a server-side language, and sees only requests by the web browsers. Since the request looks the same with and without Flash installed, there is no way to distinguish the two cases in php, or any server-side program.

You should send a website that falls back to HTML/CSS/JavaScript when Flash is available every time. And quite frankly, unless you have an advanced application (think a map application, 3D, and/or video chat), you shouldn't be using Flash in the first place for simple things like menus.

Comment: @vipul Yes. JavaScript and jQuery (written in JavaScript) is executed **client-side** and can therefore access plugin information, pretty much as in the code in your question.

Answer (score 4):

Here it is:

```
var _flash_installed = ((typeof navigator.plugins != "undefined" && typeof navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"] == "object") || (window.ActiveXObject && (new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash")) != false));
```

Comment: We need to underline, that this is purely JavaScript (client-side) solution, as the question was previously (before edit) pointed to PHP (server-side) solution. Thanks, anyway, for a very good (yet simple) solution, Ofer Zelig! :]

Answer (score 0):

This function allows the browser to know if the user has Flash support:

```
function is_flash_support() {
    var flash_support = false;
    try {
        var fo = new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash');
        if(fo) {
            flash_support = true;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        if(navigator.mimeTypes && navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash'] != undefined && navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash'].enabledPlugin) {
            flash_support = true;
        }
    }
    return flash_support;
}
```